# Error en AndroidManifest (debe comenzar y terminar por la misma entidad)

Tags: android, xml, manifest

Muy buenas, estoy programando una pequeña aplicación para conexión Bluetooth y tengo un error en el *AndroidManifest* que no alcanzo a entender. Está todo bien abierto y bien cerrado.

El error es el siguiente:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 1; Las
>   estructuras del documento XML deben empezar y finalizar en la misma
>   entidad.

Este es mi *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.bluetoothmanager">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al revisar tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` se muestra correcto, posiblemente el error lo tenías pero ahora que esta corregido no se esta sincronizando correctamente la información.

Te sugiero realices un

`Build` > `Clean Proyect`

Y posteriormente

`Build` > `Rebuild Proyect`

recordandote que al menos una Activity debe ser la que inicie al cargar nuestra aplicación para esto debes definir el intent filter en este caso a MainActivity  de esta forma:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

Este sería tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.bluetoothmanager">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Intenta colocar estas lineas entre el

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

por si fuese esto el error , ya que estas lineas son para indicarle que Activity debe arrancar cuando se inicia la aplicación, y tu no lo tienes, es posible que sea por esto